# Menu view does not render when editing profile2 profile

Tags: routes, users

I am using profile2 and "Menu Views". Why would a view that I have in the menu not return any results at all when editing a user's profile (at the url /user/XXX/edit)? The menu view works on every other page of my site.

Maybe it's because I am theming the profile editing page? I can actually display the menu theme that i'm trying to display on my site's menu on the page itself by putting code within the theme, but no matter what I do it will not display in the menu on this page.

Comment: could you tell us what the view is rendering

Comment: Normally it would render a list of links (site categories) which is created by aggregating a list of all published articles on the site and then grouping by category. In this case the list is empty on the profile editing page. There seems to be some sort of conflict.

Comment: are you passing any argument to the view?

Comment: No, there are no contextual filters or arguments.

Comment: The data is actually present in the hooks views_pre_render and views_post_render, but it does not end up in the page. Which hooks are executed afterwards? Maybe I can trace it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here ended up being that Drupal considers the page where a user edit's his profile in Profile2 an "admin" page. And, as of this writing, menu_views.module (line 159) does not process menu views on admin pages. This has been reported to the module in the form of re-opening http://drupal.org/node/1790444.

Hopefully this helps somebody else as this was a very tough one to trace down.